# Error is halting to a constant value in neural net for MNIST data

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist, cross-entropy

Edit:

I made following changes and got an accuracy of about 80%.

1. Changed epochs to 2300
2. changed learning rate to 0.000006
3. changed np.random.rand to np.random.randn

epochs and learning rate i can understand, but i have no idea whats up with rand and randn.

Error after this [image]

I am attempting digit classification of mnist database with a neural network of this structure

first layer => 784 neurons. Inputs not normalized.

hidden layer 1 => 30 neurons => activation function tanh

hidden layer 2 => 30 neurons => activation function tanh

output layer => 10 neurons => activation function softmax

cost function => cross entropy

learning rate is 0.000001, 
epochs are 30, 
batch size = 1

But the accuracy its attaining is just 11% and error is halting to a constant value (138328)( which is definitely bad ) after 20-25 epochs epochs

I have'nt put comments in the code, so if you find difficult in reading the code, just put in comments, i'll put comments in the code

learning rate => [image: Error vs No of epoch]

NeuralNetwork class is

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import time

class NueralNetwork():
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, output_size):
        self.input_layer_size = input_size
        self.hidden_layer1_size = hidden1_size
        self.hidden_layer2_size = hidden2_size
        self.output_layer_size = output_size
        np.random.seed(1)
        self.W1 = np.random.rand(self.input_layer_size, self.hidden_layer1_size)
        self.W2 = np.random.rand(self.hidden_layer1_size, self.hidden_layer2_size)
        self.W3 = np.random.rand(self.hidden_layer2_size, self.output_layer_size)
        self.b1 = np.zeros((1, self.hidden_layer1_size))
        self.b2 = np.zeros((1, self.hidden_layer2_size))
        self.b3 = np.zeros((1, self.output_layer_size))

    def train(self, input_values, label, batch_size, epochs, learning_rate, error=False):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        print("training...")
        starting_time = time.time()
        N = len(input_values)
        for j in range(epochs):
            # "j" is the epoch number
            i = 0
            print("## Epoch: ", j+1, " ##")
            print("Time Lapsed: ", time.time() - starting_time)
            self.error(input_values, label)
            while i+batch_size < N:
                sys.stdout.write("\rCompleted " + str((100*i/N)) + " in epoch " + str(j+1))
                sys.stdout.flush()

                X = input_values[i:i+batch_size]
                y = label[i:i+batch_size]
                i = i+batch_size

                z1 = X @ self.W1 + self.b1
                a1 = np.tanh(z1)
                z2 = a1 @ self.W2 + self.b2
                a2 = np.tanh(z2)
                z3 = a2 @ self.W3 + self.b3
                a3_temp = np.exp(z3)
                a3 = a3_temp / np.sum(a3_temp, keepdims=True, axis=1)

                delta4 = a3
                delta4[range(len(y)), y] -= 1
                # print(delta3)
                # print(delta3.shape)

                dw3 = a2.T @ delta4
                db3 = np.sum(delta4, axis=0, keepdims=True)
                # print(delta4.shape, " d4")
                # print(db3.shape, " db3")

                delta3 = (delta4 @ self.W3.T) * (1 - np.power(a2, 2))
                dw2 = np.dot(a1.T, delta3)
                db2 = np.sum(delta3, axis=0)

                delta2 = (delta3 @ self.W2.T) * (1 - np.power(a1, 2))
                dw1 = np.dot(X.T, delta2)
                db1 = np.sum(delta2, axis=0)

                self.W1 += -learning_rate * dw1
                self.b1 += -learning_rate * db1
                self.W2 += -learning_rate * dw2
                self.b2 += -learning_rate * db2
                self.W3 += -learning_rate * dw3
                self.b3 += -learning_rate * db3

                if error:
                    self.error(input_values, label)
            print("")


    def error(self, X, y):
        z1 = X @ self.W1 + self.b1
        a1 = np.tanh(z1)
        z2 = a1 @ self.W2 + self.b2
        a2 = np.tanh(z2)
        z3 = a2 @ self.W3 + self.b3
        a3_temp = np.exp(z3)
        a3 = a3_temp / np.sum(a3_temp, keepdims=True, axis=1)

        correct_loss = -np.log(a3[range(len(y)), y])
        data_loss = np.sum(correct_loss)
        print(data_loss)

    def show_performance(self, X, y):
        print("Error is: ", end="")

        z1 = X @ self.W1 + self.b1
        a1 = np.tanh(z1)
        z2 = a1 @ self.W2 + self.b2
        a2 = np.tanh(z2)
        z3 = a2 @ self.W3 + self.b3
        a3_temp = np.exp(z3)
        a3 = a3_temp / np.sum(a3_temp, keepdims=True, axis=1)
        y_p = np.argmax(a3, axis=1)
        self.error(X, y)
        score = 0
        for i in range(len(y)):
            if y_p[i] == y[i]:
                score += 1
        print("Score is ", score/len(y))

train_images, train_label, test_images, test_label = initial.load_data_mnist()
nn = NueralNetwork(784, 30, 30, 10)
nn.train(train_images, train_label, 1, 20, 0.000001)
nn.show_performance(test_images, test_label)
```

data is coming from here. 'data' directory has the mnist database files

```
from mnist import MNIST
import numpy as np

def load_data_mnist():
    mdata = MNIST('data')

    train_images, train_labels = mdata.load_training()
    test_images, test_labels = mdata.load_testing()

    return np.array(train_images), np.array(train_labels), np.array(test_images), np.array(test_labels)
```

Comment: Check weight initialisation, run for many iteraations,10000 and plot learning curve

Comment: Learning rate & batch size both way too small...

Comment: the error is converging to a constant value, so i dont think, increasing iterations will have a effect.

Comment: i change d learning rate to 0.000005, and the accuracy increased to 15%

Comment: where does `initial.load_data_mnist()` come from??